# How to redirect to customer login with JS

Tags: magento-1.9

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31646603/7563153) answer, which shows how to redirect to the admin login with JS:

```
window.location='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().(string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName')?>';
```

How could I redirect to customer login using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:)

```
document.location = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>';
```